# Discrepancy with TakeWhile between RandomInteger result and list on Linux

Tags: bugs, version-8, packed-arrays

**Bug introduced in 8.0.0 and fixed in 8.0.1**

---

I have to following code that solves a problem for me. The example that is given to us is as follows:
`lst = {1,-2, 3, 4,5,-3, -4, 9,7,0,8}`, predicate = `Positive`. The maximal Predicate-segments of `lst` are `{1}, {3,4,5}, {9,7}`, and `{8}`.

```
getSegments[lst_,predicate_] :=
  Module[{res= {},seg, lstcopy=lst},
    While[Length[lstcopy]>0,
      seg = TakeWhile[lstcopy,predicate[#]&];
      If[Length[seg] > 0,
        (* True *)
        AppendTo[res,seg]; 
        lstcopy=Drop[lstcopy,Length[seg]],
        (* False *)
        lstcopy=Drop[lstcopy,Length[TakeWhile[lstcopy,!predicate[#]&]]]; 
      ] (* If *)
    ] ;(* While *)
    Return[res];
  ];
```

The above code works fine for the following input:

```
In[1]:= getSegments[RandomInteger[{-100,100},10],Positive]
Out[1]= {{68,13},{59},{16},{41}}

In[2]:= getSegments[RandomInteger[{-100,100},10],Negative]
Out[2]= {{-26},{-77,-60},{-11,-78}}
```

Yet something very strange happens with the following:

```
In[3]:= getSegments[RandomInteger[{1,2},10],EvenQ]
Out[3]= {}

In[4]:= getSegments[{1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2},EvenQ]
Out[4]= {{2,2},{2,2},{2,2}}
```

This is the same for OddQ.

**Why does it treat the RandomInteger result so differently from the list?**

The input for `In[4]` is also generated with a call to RandomInteger[{1,2},10].
I did find that `seg` is always empty with the `In[3]` case, while the `False` branch of the `If` takes all the elements in the list.

**EDIT**
It is of note that I run Mathematica 8 on Linux. The above works fine on Windows versions of Mathematica.

**EDIT 2**

```
In[76]:= getSegments[RandomInteger[{1,2},5],EvenQ] // Trace
Out[76]= {{RandomInteger[{1,2},5],
{1,2,1,2,1}},getSegments[{1,2,1,2,1},EvenQ],SplitBy[{1,2,1,2,1},EvenQ]
[[If[EvenQ[First[{1,2,1,2,1}]],1,2];;All;;2]],
{SplitBy[{1,2,1,2,1},EvenQ],Split[{1,2,1,2,1},EvenQ[#1]===EvenQ[#2]&],
{(EvenQ[#1]===EvenQ[#2]&)[1,2],EvenQ[1]===EvenQ[2],{EvenQ[1],False},
{EvenQ[2],True},False===True,False},{(EvenQ[#1]===EvenQ[#2]&)
[2,1],EvenQ[2]===EvenQ[1],{EvenQ[2],True},
{EvenQ[1],False},True===False,False},{(EvenQ[#1]===EvenQ[#2]&)
[1,2],EvenQ[1]===EvenQ[2],{EvenQ[1],False},
{EvenQ[2],True},False===True,False},{(EvenQ[#1]===EvenQ[#2]&)
[2,1],EvenQ[2]===EvenQ[1],{EvenQ[2],True},
{EvenQ[1],False},True===False,False},{{1},{2},{1},{2},{1}}},
{{{{First[{1,2,1,2,1}],1},EvenQ[1],False},If[False,1,2],2},2;;All;;2},
{{1},{2},{1},{2},{1}}[[2;;All;;2]],{{2},{2}}}
```

I've trimmed down to problem to the following:

```
lst = RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10]
TakeWhile[lst, EvenQ]
TakeWhile[lst, OddQ]
```

One of the TakeWhile calls should always return some value. Yet they both give an empty list. This works fine on Windows, yet fails on Linux.

Comment: `getSegments[RandomInteger[{1,2},10], EvenQ]` works as expected on my system (Mma v8.0.4 Windows Vista 64bit).

Comment: @kguler Yes, I've tried that too and see that it works on Windows. It seems to be a Linux specific problem.

Comment: I found [an older question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4911827/618728) that relates to this.  It's apparently a known bug in version 8.0.0 so I'm adding those tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work on your system (it does mine), but perhaps this will help:

```
getSegments[lst_, test_] := 
  SplitBy[lst, test][[ If[test @ First @ lst, 1, 2] ;; ;; 2 ]]

getSegments[{1, -2, 3, 4, 5, -3, -4, 9, 7, 0, 8}, Positive]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {3, 4, 5}, {9, 7}, {8}}
> ```

---

I found [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4911827/618728) that relates to this.  It's apparently a known bug in version 8.0.0.
You will need to unpack your data before passing it to TakeWhile.

```
lst = RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10];

TakeWhile[Developer`FromPackedArray @ lst, EvenQ]
```

Comment: While that does solve the problem (not to mention in a much nicer way :)), it does not give me an answer to my problem.

Comment: @Willem I wish I had an answer for you other than "could not reproduce" but I'm using Windows.  Would you append the output of `getSegments[RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10], EvenQ] // Trace` on your system to the question?

Comment: I've added the Trace result. I also trimmed down the problem to just the TakeWhile.

Comment: @Willem sorry, I wasn't clear; I meant *your* `getSegments`, but I see that you've isolated the problem to `TakeWhile`.  I now suspect packing.  Please try: ``lst = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10];`` then `TakeWhile[lst, EvenQ]` and `TakeWhile[lst, OddQ]` and report if then works correctly.